# Cannot see my account in blocks.io

Tags: account-creation

I used scatter to create my account, saved all the private info, sent EOS tokens to a contract. Here's [txid](https://eosflare.io/tx/a8c43a0ce2227588766cf8f29719543eaad5c0e23509a19e822b1ae30f071247)

Scatter shows that my account is active on mainnet, but I cant see this through any network explorer. [link to my account](https://bloks.io/account/eoslpgkirill). Also, I cant send tokens on my account, binance rejects it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin of Scatter's telegram channel helped me

> Click the "Unlink Account" button and then go to "Add Account" and
>   click "Create". Then put that same name in and click the "Create
>   Account" button on the next page, don't need to send funds.